# Entity Framework Add-Migration cannot detect changes that I made on foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach. I was able to use Add-Migration to automatically detect when I added new table into my context. But, when I change the foreign key on one of the models, Add-Migration unable to detect the changes and generate the codes to update the foreign key.

Here is my Model

```
public class PhoneInfo
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public String ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Contact"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public String UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Contact"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public String ContactID { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

I am updating the Column(Order = 1) below

```
[ForeignKey("Contact"), Column(Order = 1)]
```

Is there any ways to make Add-Migration automatically generate codes that I needed to update the database?

Answer (score 0):

for migrations you need to execute two commands in package manager console:

```
1. Add-Migration AddOrder1ContactFK
2. Update-Database
```

Comment: I already did that. But I think since the Up() and Down() method in the DbMigration class that automatically generated when I execute Add-Migration command is empty, Update-Database would not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled property to true which is defined in the constructor of the Configuration.cs. Its default value is false when you first enable the migrations. Then rebuilt your solution and try update-database once more.